# How to send Authorization access_token to request header in Laravel using Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-response

I'm Bulid an API Authentication System. Everything I can check using `Postman` But I want to attach this mark portion `(please see the image)` that's means the header portion send from my controller or middleware with request header.

How Can I do this Stuff.
Please see my code sample.

Picture.
[image]

I try this using a middleware.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $token='Bearer '.$request->bearerToken();
    $response=$next($request);
    $response->header('Authorization',$token);

    return $response;
}
```

Registered middleware in Kernal.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

    'Header'  =>[
        \App\Http\Middleware\HeaderMiddleware::class
    ],
];
```

and my `routes\api.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','Header']], function(){
Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@details');
Route::get('test','API\PassportController@test');
});
```

When I use Middleware it's show this result in Postman.
[image]

Comment: And what is result of using this middleware? You haven't included screen of Headers tab from your response

Comment: it's show the login page. when i use the middleware

Comment: I'm updated my question please see @MarcinNabiałek

Comment: errr, isnt the `Authorization` header is for authenticating the client (the requestor), so it has nothing to do with middleware that changes the response..

Comment: How can i resolve this issue ?? @BagusTesa

Comment: `['Header','auth:api']` i;m try this way but not working @rkj

Comment: from where you are trying to access your api ? `auth:api` middleware already checking `Authorization` header then why do you need to add extra header middleware

Comment: @Gabrielle But you still included Body tab and you want to add something to header, right? So you should include what you have in Headers tab in Postman and not in body

Comment: why it had to be the middleware?

Comment: I'm try this using middleware, if you have any other options please suggest me. @BagusTesa

Comment: yes,you're right. But I want to do add authorization from my middleware, is it possible ?? @MarcinNabiałek

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to add some custom headers in middleware. To add custom header to response you need to do it like this:

```
$response = $next($request);
$response->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$request->bearerToken());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below:

```
 $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/details', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```